# DML , ML with restricted dependent types

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, dependent-types, language-design

Refering to this paper
 [Dependent ML: An Approach to Practical
Programming with Dependent Types](https://www.cs.bu.edu/~hwxi/academic/papers/JFPdml.ps)

Have defined datatype **'alist ( int )** Its not clear why they have used int as a parameter rather than a nat directly.

```
datatype ’a list (int) = 
    nil(0) | {n:nat} cons(n+1) of ’a * ’a list(n)
fun(’a)
    append (nil, ys) = ys
  | append (cons (x, xs), ys) = cons (x, append (xs, ys))
withtype {m:nat,n:nat} ’a list(m) * ’a list(n) -> ’a list(m+n)
```

In there base paper [Dependent Types in Practical Programming](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/papers/popl99.pdf) they have defines it like **’a list of nat** which makes more sense :

```
datatype ’a list = nil | cons of ’a * ’a list
typeref ’a list of nat with (* indexing the datatype ’a list with nat *)
    nil <| ’a list(0)
  | cons <| {n:nat} ’a * ’a list(n) -> ’a list(n+1)

fun(’a)
    append(nil, ys) = ys 
  | append(cons(x, xs), ys) = cons(x, append(xs, ys))
where append <| {m:nat}{n:nat} ’a list(m) * ’a list(n) -> ’a list(m+n)
```

The first declaration  looks elegant and In second its not clear  why to use <| inside where clause ? Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: This is a tough one, but sense you're asking about the specifics of the language DML, I feel like this probably belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jmite “Why was the language designed this way?” is a computer science question, though, and it's likely not to be well-received on SO (because the SO community mostly thinks that language design is a matter of whim, not science). Given that the basis for the question is a scientific question, I think this question is perfectly fine here. It would be better if it was more self-contained though: what are `int` and `nat`? Why does the use of `<|` matter?